# parsing bufferedReader data, stopping at certain characters

Tags: java, split, bufferedreader, record

I am new to java, still working on a variety of things.  I have an issue with a read/write package I am creating.  I have the writing down (both text and randomaccess file types) but my issue comes from using a bufferedReader to gather the input of my text file, stopping at "," and then taking that information and parsing it to appropriate data formats before sending it off to a record method that I have.

My format is as such : text.txt file = name, age, salary.   In this case, any number will do but in the file it is a String separated by commas, ex :"James, 22, 1500.20"

My method is a mess, this is where I am well and truly stuck

```
package l2Reader;

import java.io.*;

import l2Record.Record;

public class Text extends Reader {

private BufferedReader in;

/**
 * Opens a file of employee records for reading
 * @param fileName -- name of file to open
 * @throws IOException -- if fileName is null or 
 * unable to open the file for any reason.
 */
public void open(String fileName) throws IOException{
in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
}

/**
 * Reads the next employee data Record.
 * @return the Record read.
 * @throws IOException if an underlying read command throws an exception or
 * the data in the file is not able to be interpreted as a valid employee record.
 */ 
public Record read() throws IOException {
try {
  String temp = "";
     while((temp = in.readLine()) != null)
     if(temp.trim().length() > 0){
        temp =temp + in.readLine();
     }
     System.out.println(temp);
        String name = "nub";
     byte age = 0;
     float salary = 10;
     if (name == null){
     throw new IOException();
      }
       //return a record
     return new Record(name, age, salary);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw e;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //throw new IOException();
    e.printStackTrace();
    throw new IOException();
    }
}

/**
 * @return true if there is no more data to be read, false otherwise.
 */
public boolean eof(){
boolean eof = true;
 try{ 
  return ! (in.read() != -1);
  }
 catch (Exception e) { 
 return true;
  }   
 }
          /**
 * Closes the file
 * @throws IOException -- if unable to close the file
 */
public void close() throws IOException{
  try{
  in.close();
  }catch (Exception e) {
  throw new IOException();
  }
   }
}
```

**edited to show entire class

Answer (score 0):

```
public Record read() throws IOException {
  String line = in.readLine();
  if (line == null) {
    throw new IOException(); //maybe return null?
  }

  String[] values = line.split(",");
  String name = values[0];
  int age = Integer.parseInt(values[1]);
  float salary = Float.parseFloat(values[2]);

  return new Record(name, age, salary);
}
```

but maybe the problem is not here. I can't see where you initialized your bufferedReader. Maybe describe the process to help us.

Comment: I can fill this out more.

Comment: I created a text file using a write method (created a printWriter file .txt, which works) that I need to open and return as a record in the read method.  Currently I have provided default variables as placeholders for the actual work.  Right now, my read is providing me nothing but null values and I can't work with those.  I applied the "temp" section to try and find out what my file is returning, which so far is all null.

Comment: the "while" as no brackets so it only touch the if condition. So presently, you read all the file and check the "if" before doing anything else. At the last iteration of "in.readline()" there is no more line to read so it returns "null". This is why you always get null. Put those brackets on and that will be it. If you want to get only one record from read, use if instead of while (maybe you used while for debug).

Comment: Just a tip like that, you don't need to try-catch if you are going to throw exception again. Just add it in function signature like you did and that's it. It's just more clean ;)

Comment: Thank you GabLeg, while I didn't see this until later I actually used something very similar to this, and it worked.

Comment: The pleasure is all mine :)